# Maximum product contiguous subarray

Tags: python, array

I have come up with the following solution to find the maximum product for a contiguous sub-array:

```py
def maxProduct(nums):
    
    max_prod = [0]*len(nums)
    min_prod = [0]*len(nums)
    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        min_prod[i] = min(nums[i], min_prod[i-1]*nums[i], max_prod[i-1]*nums[i])
        max_prod[i] = max(nums[i], min_prod[i-1]*nums[i], max_prod[i-1]*nums[i])
        
   
    return max(max_prod)
```

Current solution is `O(n)` in space, trying to find `O(1)` solution for space, but I keep seem to missing it. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Follow [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for variable and function naming convention. Both the variables and function names should have `snake_case` names.
2. You can [use `enumerate`](https://devdocs.io/python%7E3.8/library/functions#enumerate) to get index and value while iterating a list.

---

For constant space solution, instead of using a list to keep track of current max and min products, use a variable for both positive product and negative product. If the current number is \$ 0 \$, reset them both to \$ 1 \$ (They should be initialised as \$ 1 \$ as well). At the end of for-loop (inside the loop), keep updating your `current_max` value to keep track of max product encountered so far.

---

As edge cases, you may also consider returning (or raising errors) when input was empty etc.